# Using "sed" command in linux to replace text

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a specific question related to the usage of sed in linux.

Suppose there is a String "Hello to the world version 1.0.0.1"

Now I want to take the new version from a file and update this

For example the new version is present in /etc/NewVersion

So can we do something like this :

```
$newVersion = "/etc/NewVersion"
sed -i "s/1.0.0.1/$newVersion/g" /etc/motd
```

Also is there a way that suppose the last number of the version changes, from 1.0.0.1 to something else like 1.0.0.2 , how can i make it generic that no matter what the version Im able to fetch the new version from the file path and update it with sed?

Comment: change that first line to `newVersion=$(cat /etc/NewVersion)` and you should be golden. That will take the stdout of the `cat /etc/NewVersion` command and stick it into variable `newVersion` which you can use in your `sed` command. Of course you may end up with other issues depending on what is in that file...

Comment: `sed -i "s~1\.0\.0\.[0-9]*~$(</etc/NewVersion)~" /etc/motd`

Comment: One question, why are we using "~" instead of "/" . What's the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

sed doesn't really support passing parameters very well. A better solution would be awk:

```
awk -v overs="1.0.0.1" -v newver="1.0.0.2" '$0 ~ overs { flag=0;match($0,overs);print substr($0,1,RSTART-1)newver } $0 !~ overs { flag=1 } flag' /etc/motd
```

Pattern match for the old version number. If it exists, stop the line printing by setting flag=0. Then match the old version number and print the rest of the line plus the new version number. Otherwise, set flag=1 and print the line.

Answer (score 0):

With sed and a bash [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution) to read from `/etc/NewVersion`, and assuming that your New Version text will never contain a forward-slash:

```
sed -i "s/\(Hello to the world version \).*/\1"$(</etc/NewVersion)"/" /etc/motd
```

This replaces (with `-i` "in-place" editing of /etc/motd) the string "Hello to the world version ", followed by anything, with the "Hello" text (captured with the parenthesis and referred to by the `\1`, followed by the contents of `/etc/NewVersion`.

Or, if you want to allow any contents in `/etc/NewVersion`, [use ed](https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html):

```
ed -s /etc/motd <<< $'1c\nHello to the world version '"$(</etc/NewVersion)"$'\n.\nwq'
```

This edits /etc/motd in script (`-s`) mode, passing it the quoted string as input (commands for ed):

1. on line `1`, `c`hange it to:
2. `Hello to the world version` followed by the contents of /etc/NewVersion
3. `.` stop input mode for the `c` command
4. `w`rite and `q`uit